# Modify global variable from recursive function does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, variables, recursion, sum, global

I attempt to make a recursive function to calculate sum from 1 to n using global variable, but it did not seem to work as expected.

Could someone explain for me why? Below is the code in javascript.

```
s = 0;

function sum(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    s = s + n + sum(n - 1);
  }
  return 0;
}

sum(5);

console.log('The sum from 1 to 5 is ' + s); // this return wrong value
```

My intention is to create a side-effect on global variable s. So I assume all stack frames will be called in this order and each time it pops (from the bottom up), s value will be updated accordingly. Please correct if I understand this wrong.

```
s = s + 5 + sum(4)  // s = 10 + 5 + 0
return 0
------------------
s = s + 4 + sum(3)  // s = 6 + 4 + 0
return 0
------------------
s = s + 3 + sum(2)  // s = 3 + 3 + 0
return 0
------------------
s = s + 2 + sum(1)  // s = 0 + 2 + 1 
return 0
------------------
return 1            // s = 0 (from global)
```

Comment: You never return sum. Just 1 and 0.

Comment: @H77: Just modified a little bit

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` statement you need to return `s` and remove the `return 0` part. In one line statement you can write

```js
s = 0;

function sum(n) {
   return n === 1 ? 1 : s += n + sum(n - 1);
}

sum(5);

console.log('The sum from 1 to 5 is ' + s);
```

Without global variable

```js
function sum(n) {
   return n === 1 ? 1 : n + sum(n - 1);
}

console.log('The sum from 1 to 5 is ' + sum(6));
```

Comment: I intentionally only return 0 and 1 to try making a side effect. Just edited a little bit, could you take a look? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I have found out the answer quite neatly. It seems like the Javascript interpreter evaluated `s` on the right hand side a bit too early, hence the popped stack frame did not behave as expected. So here I will post my own answer. Quite happy with it :)

```
s = 0;

function sum(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    q = n + sum(n-1);   // break into 2  
    s += q;             // assignments like this
  }
  return 0;
}

sum(5);

console.log('The sum from 1 to 5 is ' + s); // this will be correct now!
```